# Can't launch a video from uri using LaunchFileAsync

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

For a windows 8 App, in C#/Xaml I would like to launch a video with a media Player on the computer using Launcher.LaunchFileAsync.

I have a video File from a url and I am using this code :

```
     var uri = new Uri(myUrl,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

            var file = await StorageFile.CreateStreamedFileFromUriAsync("aaa", uri, RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(uri));

            if (file != null)
            {
                // Launch the retrieved file
                var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);

                if (success)
                {
                    // File launched
                }
                else
                {
                    // File launch failed
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Could not find file
            }
```

This is is actually the sample code from the documentation of LaunchFileAsync. It seemed fine to me but success is always false. 
Do you have any idea why? 
Is it possible to use LaunchFileAsync for a video in a url?
Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I was trying to play an .mp3 file from a specific file path location.

I couldn't open the file with **StorageFile.CreateStreamedFileFromUriAsync**. I was getting invalid argument exceptions or unauthorized access errors.

Try to replace change the lines:

```
            String myUrl = @"ms-appx:///sources/sounds/ffd19.mp3";          
            var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
```

The only downfall is that the file has to be registed as a resource of the project.

In my case the .mp3 was located in the sources/sounds/ folder, in the same folder with the application files, in the solution explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused by what your codes says.

```
var file = await StorageFile.CreateStreamedFileFromUriAsync("aaa", uri, RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(uri));
```

The "file" get the function's return, but what the function return is an object of StorageFile which you could refer to Window.Storage.StorageFile.

I think this may be the problem, but I don't know how to right it.

Furthermore, the function "LaunchFileAsync()" has restrictions on what types of file it can launch, which may cause this problem as well.

Sorry for my no-answer advice. That's all.